# Displaying a MTLTexture in a macOS playground by converting it to CImage or other working format

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am having trouble converting a MTLTexture into a format that can easily be displayed inside of a macOS playground.

There are a variety of solutions I have found however none of them are updated to Swift 4 and after I update them I have found no success with them. Additionally all of the better maintained (Swift 4) implementations convert to a UIImage which is not available on macOS.

What format should I convert to? How can I do the conversion?